# updating eclipse.ini file in windows 7

Tags: java, eclipse

This is my eclipse.ini file.

```
 -startup
```

plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher_1.1.0.v20100507.jar
--launcher.library
plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.win32.win32.x86_1.1.1.R36x_v20100810
-product
org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256M
-showsplash
org.eclipse.platform
-vm
C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\javaw.exe
--launcher.XXMaxPermSize
256m
--launcher.defaultAction
openFile

-vmargs
-Dosgi.requiredJavaVersion=1.5
-Duser.name=naval13490@gmail.com
-Xms40m
-Xmx512m

When I am starting eclipse it is showing me this message. 
**It is showing me java was started but returned exit code=13**

I am using windows 7 64bit and jdk version 17.0.0_01.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ensure you're not trying to use 32-bit Eclipse with 64-bit Windows + JRE/JDK. Mixing up the two generally leads to this error.